# How to use custom variables in Magento 2?

Tags: admin-panel, magento-2.1.3, custom-variable

I have seen email templates to use built-in custom variables. Can someone explain how to use `System -> Other Settings -> Custom Variables`? For example category count, which will show in frontend.

Comment: Did my answer solve your query?

Comment: @VivekKumar, No, I am looking for something configure variable from backend and it will work in the frontend. Like frontend showing product counts category beside.

Comment: I thought you asked about custom variable at mentioned path at admin

Answer (score 1):

From what I have used custom variable, it is only for passing admin manageable value to your code, you can access it as follows;

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->loadByCode('custom-variable-code');
$plain_value = $model->getPlainValue();
```

**EDIT:**

As asked by @Jonas de Herdt  if you want to get store specific value for the variable you just need to pass the store code along with the custom variable code as follows;

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->loadByCode('custom-variable-code', 'store-code');
$plain_value = $model->getPlainValue();
```

**Reminder that you should not use objectmanager directly in your code**

Comment: How to add store base url in custom varible in admin?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but store url can be easily fetched using Storemanagerinterface so it doesn't need to be in admin variable.

Comment: No. I want as like {{store url ='' }} as like this added in static block content

Comment: I don't think that kind of wild cards are supported in variables, it is primarily meant for storing plain text or html.

Comment: Totally agree with previous comment. It's your supplied text or html variable. Not a variable variable. If you want something dynamic write some bespoke block logic and embed it in your template, block or CMS page.

Comment: How do i get the translation of this object? In database there are multiple entries with store id's 7,6,9 etc. But the model always returns the value of store id 0.

Comment: Using the objectManager is highly risking and should be used at all. Please use class dependencies, or interfaces.

Comment: @PetarBorisovski I've already mentioned that in the answer ..

Answer (score 0):

Plain text.

But where they come in handy is that custom variables can be used in CMS style content. So pages, blocks and email templates.

This is really helpful let's say if you've got a custom telephone number that's different from store number or similar you want to come through in templates.

You should be able to insert using WYSIWYG

You would be surprised how often I see someone insert content manually which could be handled like this.

With some code change you could get these variables to come through on printed invoices etc.

Once all in place custom variable value can then be edited within admin.